# Coffeescript express template

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, express

I want to use the following template for my coffeescript express app

https://github.com/twilson63/express-coffee

However I am unfamiliar with express and the app/ directory has an index.js file that seems to run the server. what would be the correct code structure to add actions/controllers/routes to this template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should check out [skeleton](https://github.com/EtienneLem/skeleton). It's a package that generates a CoffeeScript application template for you and makes use of MVC. I did find, however, that express-coffee has a pretty good cakefile (though it seems to depend on global packages too much for my liking). I combined ideas from both and wrote [frappe](https://github.com/dweldon/frappe). It's a template very similar to the output from skeleton, with a few things tweaked for my personal taste. Anyway, have a look at those - hopefully you will find what you are looking for.

Comment: Also, express-coffee seems to depends on doccoo-husky, which doesn't work properly in windows 7 and 8.